# For Loop in Device Function on Compute Capability 1.1 Device

Tags: cuda

I wrote a `__device__` function that uses a `for` loop. It works on GTX640 card (compute capability 2.1), but not on 9500GT (compute capability 1.1).

The function is roughly like this:

```
__device__ void myFuncD(float4 *myArray, float4 *result, uint index, uint foo, uint *here, uint *there)
{
    uint j;
    float4 myValue = myArray[index];
    uint idxHere = here[foo];
    uint idxThere = there[foo];
    float4 temp;

    for(j=idxHere;j<idxThere;j++){
        temp = myArray[j];

        //do things with myValue and temp, write result to *result
        result->x += /* some calculations with myValue.x and temp.x */
        result->y += /* some calculations with myValue.y and temp.y */
        result->z += /* some calculations with myValue.z and temp.z */
    }
}

__global__ void myKernelD(float4 *myArray, float4 *myResults, uint *here, uint *there)
{
    uint index = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;

    float4 result = = make_float4(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    uint foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4;

    //compute foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4 based on myArray[index]

    myFuncD(myArray, &result, index, foo1, here, there);
    myFuncD(myArray, &result, index, foo2, here, there);
    myFuncD(myArray, &result, index, foo3, here, there);
    myFuncD(myArray, &result, index, foo4, here, there);

    myResults[index] = result;
}
```

On GTX460, `myResults` has proper values, but on 9500GT every components of its members are all zeroes.

How can I achieve the same effect with a compute capability 1.1 device?

Comment: WHat do you mean, specifically, by "it doesn't work on 9500 GT"? I don't see anything specific about the code that would be illegal on SM 1.1. In particular, I don't see the recursion-like behavior mentioned in the title.

Comment: So now you have changed the question considerably so that all mentions of recursion are gone. But you haven't said what doesn't work on the compute 1.1 device. Please edit your question again to include a description of what the problem is.

Comment: I meant `for` loop. Sorry for that. I read a discussion on another question that SM 1.1 doesn't support recursion and got the term mixed up. Also, the `__device__` function is a `void` one, and `result` is accessed using `->` operator. On 9500GT, every member of `myResults` is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0). Side question: Am I right in assuming that using float4 is better than using float3 even though I don't need the w component?

Comment: Does your code check for errors reported by the CUDA runtime? I suspect you just have a runtime error and the kernel is not running...

Comment: Ah, you're right, it reported "too many resources requested for launch". So what might cause that?

Comment: Finally! Reducing the number of threads got rid of the problem. Thank you so much, both of you.

Answer (score 1):

The user was trying to use too many threads per block to launch, and was getting the error "too many resources requested for launch".  Decreasing threads per block allowed the kernel to launch.